# How to add a boolean filter based on a parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(string location, string role, bool excludeHeadOffice )
{
    var users = from u in DataContext.Users
        where
            (u.location == location || location == null) &&
            (u.role == role || role == null)

    return users;           
}
```

What I want to do is, and an additional filter like this:

```
(excludeHeadOffice && u.location != "ho")
```

How can I add this expression to the existing where clause?

**Update**
If excludeHeadOffice is true, then it should use the filter

```
(excludeHeadOffice && u.location != "ho")
```

Otherwise it should work as before using:

```
 (u.location == location || location == null)
```

Comment: Guessing you want to use `isHeadOffice` as a switch to enable filtering on `u.location = "ho"`?

Comment: If excludeHeadOffice is false, it should work as I have it now.  If it is true, then it should filter based on:  ```(excludeHeadOffice && u.location != "ho")```

Comment: There is no `excludeHeadOffice` in your method,.

Comment: @JLRishe sorry typo,fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to think it through and come up with the necessary boolean logic:

```
where
    (
     (excludeHeadOffice && u.location != "ho") ||
     (!excludeHeadOffice && (u.location == location || location == null))
    ) &&
    (u.role == role || role == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(string location, string role, bool excludeHeadOffice = false)
{
    var users = from u in DataContext.Users
    where
        (u.location == location || location == null) &&
        (u.role == role || role == null)

    if(excludeHeadOffice)
    {
      return users.Where(u => u.location != "headOfficeLocation" && u.location !="ho");
    }
    return users;           
 }
```

Comment: The code within the if statement will not modify the `users` variable. You would need `users = users.Where(...`.

Comment: Added the **return** keyword now. Forgot to add that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Build your query in more than one statement.

This will be (arguably) easier to build this with extension methods:

```
var query = DataContext.Users.AsQueryable();

if (excludeHeadOffice)
    query = query.Where(x => x.location != "ho");
else if (location != null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.location == location);

if (role != null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.role == role);

return query;
```

The idea here is that you start with a base "get me everything" query, and you keep adding onto it with if statements.